# Android object animator rotate relative to self xml

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to create an `Object Animator` rotation in xml. Right now the rotation seems to have the pivot point set to 0,0 so how can I change the pivot point to be the center of the view?

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="180"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>
```

Comment: `View#setPivot*()`

Comment: So there's no way to do this via xml?

Comment: what for if you have to use java anyway (in order to start your animator)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RotateDrawable`. Try below snippet:

**Programmatically:**

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotation);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

**anim/rotation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

Here is the result:

[image]